# Matplotlib - Python- GetDist tool - Overlapping 2 triangle plots (triplots) by calling twice the plot function: issue of visible priority between both

Tags: python, matplotlib, z-index, overlap, covariance-matrix

In python3, I am faced to 2 issues using the tool `GetDist` [tool to produce triplot of covariance matrix](https://getdist.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

**1)** Currently, I can plot 2 covariance matrixes on the same figure by only one call of the plotting function ([triangle_plot](https://getdist.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plots.html?highlight=triangle_plot#getdist.plots.GetDistPlotter.triangle_plot)). Specifying as first input the list of covariance matrix to plot is enough to have the (1 sigma,2 sigma) contours of each matrix. Here an example of triplot produced by 2 covariance matrixes (filled area correspond to 1 sigma confidence level (68%) and shaded to 2 sigma C.L (95%)). the color identifies each matrix (red and blue here) :

[image: contours 1 sigma and 2 sigma of each matrix]

My main goal is that I want to give priority in overlapping by descending order like this :

```
1) 1 sigma blue disk of smallest ellipse (blue)
2) 1 sigma red disk of largest ellipse (red)
3) 2 sigma blue disk of smallest ellipse (shaded blue)
4) 2 sigma red disk of smallest ellipse (shaded red)
```

Whereas in default behavior, I have the following descending priority :

```
1) 1 sigma blue disk of smallest ellipse (blue)
2) 2 sigma blue disk of smallest ellipse (shaded blue)
2) 1 sigma red disk of largest ellipse (red)
4) 2 sigma red disk of smallest ellipse (shaded red)
```

Here the script producing this figure above :

```
g.triangle_plot([matrix1, matrix2],
                names,
                filled = True,                
                legend_labels = ['1240', '1560'],
                legend_loc = 'upper right',
                contour_colors = ['red','darkblue'],
                line_args = [{'lw':2, 'color':'red'},
                {'lw':2, 'color':'darkblue'}],
                )
```

Finally, I just would like that 1 sigma red disk not to be hidden by the 2 sigma blue shaded.

Here an example of what I want (caution, there is an inversion between red and blue compared to my triplot above) :

[image: example of wanted overlap]

Don't care about the yellow contours. As you can see, the 1 sigma blue disk has the priority over 2 red shaded sigma disk. This is exactly the same behavior that I want.

In my above triplot, I tried a lot to play with alpha parameters but it's a mess since colors are mixed and don't correspond any more to the legend (red and blue).

**2)** Given the fact that I didn't find to change this priority in the source of `GetDist`, I tried to call twice the function `triangle_plot` with one matrix for each call.

But unfortunately, there is no overlap of the 2 plots after the 2 calls. Only one color triplot is appearing (the one of the last call). For example, If I do these 2 consecutive calls like this (`matrix 2` represent the largest red ellipse and `matrix1` the smallest ellipse) :

```
g.triangle_plot([matrix2],
                names,
                filled = True,                
                legend_labels = ['1560'],
                legend_loc = 'upper right',
                contour_colors = ['darkblue'],
                contours = 0,
                num_plot_contours = 0,
                line_args = [{'lw':2, 'color':'darkblue'}]
                )

g.triangle_plot([matrix1],
                names,
                filled = True,                
                legend_labels = ['1240'],
                legend_loc = 'upper right',            
                contour_colors = ['red'],
                contours = 1,
                num_plot_contours = 1,
                line_args = [{'lw':2, 'color':'red'}]
                )
```

Is it possible to keep the first triplot (matrix 2 represented in red) and call again the `triangle_plot` function to overlap, over this first triplot, the second triplot (in blue)?

Indeed, this would allow me to play with the identifier of Confidence level (C.L : 68% or 95%) and then solve this issue of priority.

Unfortunately, the overlap is not working when I call 2 times the triangle_plot function: only the last call is kept, the first seems to be removed from the plot.

What is the method to force an overlap on this kind of triplot (overlap the contours but not the labels and ticks)? We could think a priori this is simple since the triplots are just boxes/subplots) but I can't just manage to perform this overlapping. I have tried to insert between the 2 calls :

```
plt.show(block=False)  # do not block
```

but this doesn't work. I think this is due to the fact that I save the figure in a file at the end :

```
# Save figure
g.fig.savefig('Comparison_Overlap.pdf')
```

### Update 1

Thanks to Stef. Just a last question : horizontal and vertical xticks are hidden by the contours and filled area, I don't know which is the `zorder`of these latter. Here 2 examples illustrating this issue :

[image: first example of xticks masked]

you can see that the xtick corresponding to 0.95 is masked.

[image: second example of xticks masked]

you can see that the right bottom xtick is also masked.

### Update 2

The solution of `@Stef` works perfectly but it remains one little problem: the xticks and yticks are hidden by the contours.

By default, the `z-order`of of xticks is given by :

```
g.fig.axes[0].xaxis.get_major_ticks()[0].zorder
```

that returns : `0`

So, when I plot my contours, I put after `triangle_plot` :

```
for ax in g.fig.axes:
  geo = ax.get_geometry()
  if (geo[2]-1) // geo[0] > (geo[2]-1) % geo[0]:
    for c,z in zip(ax.collections, [-1.7, -1.5, -0.1, -1.6, -1.4, -0.1]):
      c.zorder = z
```

This way, I can have contours not to be hidden by contours. For example, like this below :

[image: xtick no hidden]

This solution is not very easy since I have to deal with negative values (`[-1.7, -1.5, -0.1, -1.6, -1.4, -0.1]`).

Now, Thanks to `@Stef`, I can modify this value of  `g.fig.axes[0].xaxis.get_major_ticks()[0].zorder`, for example equal to `3` by doing :

```
# Modify z-order 
for mt in g.fig.axes[0].xaxis.get_major_ticks():
  mt.zorder = 3
for mt in g.fig.axes[0].yaxis.get_major_ticks():
  mt.zorder = 3
```

But if I do just after that :

```
for ax in g.fig.axes:
  geo = ax.get_geometry()
  if (geo[2]-1) // geo[0] > (geo[2]-1) % geo[0]:
    for c,z in zip(ax.collections, [1.6, 1.8, 2, 1.7, 1.9, 2]):
      c.zorder = z
```

xticks remain hidden by contours whereas threshold is set to `3` : I don't understand this behavior :

[image: xtick hidden]

What might be wrong?

### Update 3

Here the last things I tried to fix my issue about the priority that I want on ticks, i.e make appear the xticks/yticks in front of contours and not the opposite as it occurs for instant.

If I print the values of `zorder` by default of `get_major_ticks()` and `get_ticklines()[0])`, I get :

```
print('zorder1 = ', g.fig.axes[0].xaxis.get_major_ticks()[0].zorder)
print('zorder2 = ', g.fig.axes[0].xaxis.get_ticklines()[0].zorder)
```

==>

```
zorder1 =  0
zorder2 =  2.01
```

What's the difference between `get_major_ticks()` and `get_ticklines()` ?

You can understand why I can manage to set ticks in front of all contours, i.e by setting negative values in the solution given by `@Stef` :

```
for ax in g.fig.axes:
  geo = ax.get_geometry()
  if (geo[2]-1) // geo[0] > (geo[2]-1) % geo[0]:
    for c,z in zip(ax.collections, [-1.7, -1.5, -0.1, -1.6, -1.4, -0.1]):
      c.zorder = z
```

I can manage to modify the `zorder2` above by putting :

```
g.fig.axes[0].tick_params(zorder=3)
```

But impossible for me to modifiy the `zorder1`(equal to `0`by default).

How could I change this `0` value for `zorder1` (which makes reference to `get_ticklines()`) ?

Comment: **IMPORTANT CORRECTION IN THE DESCRIPTION OF MY BOUNTY** : I wanted to say : " `I want to overlap the 2 plots (with the appropriate order of contours that I want, with red one and blue one like in the legend) but not the labels or ticks on both axis.` "

Comment: Isn't really anyone who could indicate me how to overlap the contours in each subplot by calling several times the `GetDist` function `g.triangle_plot` ?

Comment: So have you tried tweaking the Z-order property already?

Comment: @BastienHarkins. Thanks for your answer. I don't know this `Z-order property` : how could it be used in python matplotlib ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of hacky but you can change the `zorder` for the contours afterwards. For this we take the lower triangular plots and set the `zorder` properties of the path and line collections. They appear in the following order:

1. filled area for 2 sigma of 1st sample
2. filled area for 1 sigma of 1st sample
3. contour lines for 1st sample
4. filled area for 2 sigma of 2nd sample
5. filled area for 1 sigma of 2nd sample
6. contour lines for 2nd sample

Originally all filled areas have `zorder` `1` and all lines `2`. We set them as required to e.g. `17, 19, 21, 18, 20, 21`.

Example:

```
from getdist import plots, gaussian_mixtures
samples1, samples2 = gaussian_mixtures.randomTestMCSamples(ndim=4, nMCSamples=2)
g = plots.get_subplot_plotter()
g.triangle_plot([samples1, samples2], filled=True, legend_labels = ['Contour 1', 'Contour 2'])

for ax in g.fig.axes:
    geo = ax.get_geometry()
    if (geo[2]-1) // geo[0] > (geo[2]-1) % geo[0]:
       for c,z in zip(ax.collections, [17,19,21,18,20,21]):
           c.zorder = z
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot ! your solution works perfectly, that's why I award bounty to you.   Just a last question, without wanting to be boring : which are the `zorder` of xticks vert    ically and horizontally since they are hidden by the contours and filled area. I illustrate this issue in the screen capture in **UPDATE1**. How to fix this problem ?

Comment: ticklines have zorder of 2.01 (`g.fig.axes[0].xaxis.get_ticklines()[0].zorder`). So in order to fix the hidden ticks issue you could use `[1.6, 1.8, 2, 1.7, 1.9, 2]` instead of `[17, 19, 21, 18, 20, 21]`.

Comment: I wanted to set xtick in front of all contours, so I followed your method and by printing the `z-order`of major ticks : `print('zorder = ', g.fig.axes[0].xaxis.get_major_ticks()[0].zorder)`that returns 0. So I modified your suggestion above by using negative values like this : `[-1.7, -1.5, -0.1, -1.6, -1.4, -0.1]` :  it works but  it would be easier to work with positive values. Is there a way to change manually the `z-order` of major ticks ? Regards

Comment: You can add this to the loop over the axes: `for mt in ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks():`     `mt.zorder = 3` (or whatever value you'd like, then the same for `yaxis`)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, xticks verticals and horizontals are hidden by doing : `# Modify z-order for xtick
for mt in ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks():
  mt.zorder = 3
for mt in ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks():
  mt.zorder = 3`  and     `for c,z in zip(ax.collections, [1.6, 1.8, 2, 1.7, 1.9, 2]):
      c.zorder = z` . Could you see an error from me ? thanks

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know why your tick lines are below the contours. The actual lines have a zorder of 2.01: `g.fig.axes[0].xaxis.get_major_ticks()[0].tick1line.zorder`, so the should be above the contours.

Comment: .I know you helped yet me a lot but I have put more descriptions about this last issue in my **UPDATE 2**. I you could take a look, this would be kind.

Comment: I don't have a real solution nor do I understand why setting the tick's zorder doen't have any effect here (`g.fig.axes[0].xaxis.set_tick_params(zorder=...)` etc.). If you don't like negative values then `[0.6,0.8,2,0.7,0.9,2]` will also work fine. It seems that the re-odered z-values should be less than 1 in order to have the ticks appear over them. Can you live with zorder-values between 0 and 1 instead of between 1 and 2? It doesn't seem to be a big deal.

Comment: thanks for your patience : all I can say is that by default , `g.fig.axes[0].xaxis.get_major_ticks()[0].zorder` returns `0`, that's why I am obliged to put negative values. Is there a command who could allow to increase this value `0`?

Comment: it's not the zorder of `get_major_ticks()` that you need pay attention to but the zorder of the ticklines themselves (which is 2.01, see my last but one comment). Did you try my proposal (`[0.6,0.8,2,0.7,0.9,2]`)?  It works for me (matplotlib version 3.3.1).

Comment: ok, I found the trick with your last comment : I did simply the following loop : `for tick in g.fig.axes[0].xaxis.get_major_ticks(): tick.tick1line.zorder = 3`. good job, thanks !

Comment: .You helped me a lot for this post. If it doesn't bore you, could you take a look on my new problem located here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64861082/matplotlib-issue-of-overlap-as-a-function-of-the-smallest-areas-of-1-confidenc#64861082 . Thanks in advance